# Apache Ignite sync data added using JDBC with persistent datastore

Tags: java, mysql, caching, jdbc, ignite

Apache Ignite provides JDBC driver and write-behind caching features.

Is there a way to sync data between Ignite and MySQL using write-behind strategy if data is added to Ignite using its JDBC driver?

The data flow is as follows:
app -`Ignite JDBC driver`-> Ignite -`MySQL JDBC driver`-> MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use SQL (cache queries or Ignite JDBC) to operate on data in Ignite, then read-through, write-through and write-behind semantics is not respected for the configured cache store.

You need to load data into cache, using [IgniteCache#loadCache(...)](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/IgniteCache.html#loadCache-org.apache.ignite.lang.IgniteBiPredicate-java.lang.Object...-) method, for example first to be able to query it from SQL.

If you need write-behind semantics, then you should use cache key-value API.

Another option is to abandon MySQL and use [Ignite native persistence](https://apacheignite.readme.io/v2.4/docs/distributed-persistent-store). This way data will be preserved on cluster restarts. It allows you operate on data from any API and eliminates the need to replicate it to another database.

Comment: the problem is that the whole infrastructure relies on the existence of this data in MySQL, at least eventual. I wonder if I can make a smooth transition from MySQL to Ignite or any other technology that supports highly available in-memory data grids.

Comment: You can use cache API instead of JDBC to insert data into Ignite. In this case data will be propagated into configured 3rd party database as expected.

Comment: I think Denis is not entirely correct. You can still use SQL, but Ignite can only query the data that resides in Ignite. If you have a subset of the data in Ignite and the superset in the MySQL database, then only the subset that is in Ignite will participate in the SQL query. As far as updates or inserts go, they should be written through to the MySQL database.

Comment: @Dmitriy, are the changes made using Ignite's JDBC API propagated to  MySQL? e.g., I run an update statement using Ignite JDBC and expect that the same update will happen in the underlying 3rd party (MySQL) storage.

Comment: @IlyaZinkovich Yes, that is the case. You can find more information in this dev@ list thread: http://apache-ignite-developers.2346864.n4.nabble.com/write-through-when-using-SQL-updates-td29767.html

Comment: @Dmitry, Awesome, this is what I was looking for, thank you!